# Import sql file to MySQL in pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I have a django rest app. It works fine with sqlite. Then I switched to using mysql. After I migrated the project. I imported a sql file to MySQL database. but got an error:

```
Table 'myusername$databasename.table_name1' doesn't exist
Table 'myusername$databasename.table_name2' doesn't exist
...
```

I don't understand. This sql file was exported from the same django project.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you will need to create those tables first. That would correspond to the django command

```
./manage.py migrate
```